# Redirecting a url - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I'm working on a wordpress site, with a blog post that ends like: http://www.blog.com/?p=2. However, I need to change the wordpress settings so that posts end in the following format: http://www.blog.com/02/11/2009/this-is-a-post. When I do this, obviously it will break outside links to the post that is named http://www.blog.com/?p=2.

So my question is how can I manaully redirect a url http://www.blog.com/?p=2 to go to a working url http://www.blog.com/02/11/2009/this-is-a-post ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to figure out exactly what you are asking. Do you need to implement some kind of "redirector" yourself, or are you looking for a feature in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those links should still work when you make the .htaccess file that Wordpress gives you.

You can go into the Wordpress admin, then under settings select permalinks. Here you can choose the format of the links. Wordpress will try to create an .htaccess for you, but if it can't, it will give you the code so you can create the .htaccess file yourself. Add this file to the root of your blog. Both formats of the links you mention will still work and the .htaccess file will actually automatically redirect the visitor to the updated URL format.

Comment: Thanks, the .htaccess had been deleted. I created a new one and copied in the rules, which worked fine.